# Moving data from one mySQL Table field to another Table field where each table has a matching id

Tags: mysql

I need to move all the data from table FCSTMR field CSTYPE to table customers2 field customers_group_pricing.
The value stored in FCSTMR CS_ENCSUNIQUE matches that stored in customers2 customers_id.

I tried using the following mysql, but it didn't move any data at all.

```
UPDATE customers2
SET `customers_group_pricing` = (
SELECT `CSTYPE`
FROM FCSTMR
WHERE CS_ENCSUNIQUE = customers2.customers_id);
```

Where did i go wrong with this? I'm assuming something to do with the WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [this](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/databases/threads/300670/mysql-how-to-use-update-with-select) question's last comment. I think it is similar to yours.

Comment: Hmm, I tried

UPDATE customers2
    INNER JOIN
    FCSTMR
    ON customers2.customers_id = FCSTMR.CS_ENCSUNIQUE
    SET customers2.customers_group_pricing = FCSTMR.CSTYPE
and still nothing was set.